# Form won't submit properly on the front page

Tags: 6, forms

I have placed a form on the front page of my Drupal 6 site using `drupal_get_form('mymodule_form')`. I have not done anything different than usual, and I have implemented a validation handler called `mymodule_form_validate()`.

The form displays properly, and posts to '/', as it should. I have put a form_set_error() into the validation handler to test that it is working. The validation handler is never hit when the form is submitted.

However, if I use `drupal_get_form()` to put the form on an internal page, it works as it should.

What is going on here? Is there something that is preventing forms from being used on the front page of a Drupal site?

Comment: @Chris Cohen How did you put a form in the front page?

Comment: Do you have a separate front page template (ie, page-front.tpl.php)? If so, are you sure you're outputting $messages in that template? Maybe it's a longshot answer, but it would cause the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Thanks, but $messages is being printed. There is only one page template, called page.tpl.php.

Comment: I am putting a form in the front page by using drupal_get_form('mymodule_form'), as I mentioned above. What other information do you need?

Comment: @Chris Cohen Are you using PHP code as content of a node that is shown as front page or in the front page, or are you using a module that defines a menu callback for, e.g., http://example.com/front-page and that path is then used as front page?

Comment: The front page is just 'node' (the default) and it has a line in page.tpl.php that says if (drupal_is_front_page()) { print drupal_get_form('mymodule_form'); } (or code to that effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that I needed to make sure the form did not submit to the front page. I needed to set up a custom path for #action on the form, and make sure there was a callback defined in a module.

When landing on that callback, the validation and submit handlers successfully fire. I can then redirect users back to <front> if they are successful. The downside is that on error, there needs to be a separate page where the form is displayed. I couldn't find a way to show the error on the front page itself.

This is good enough for what I need. Thanks for the suggestions in the comments.